# Cargar JLabel desde MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy trabajando en Java y necesito colocar un jLabel que obtenga información desde la Base de datos, en este caso es un "Numero de Registro" cada vez que se habra el Formulario debe traer el nombre y cargarlo en dicho Jlabel. He intentado varias formas y aun no puedo realizarlo.

```
private void numeros() throws SQLException{
    String SQL= ("select max(nregistro) from muestras");
    Statement pst = cn.prepareStatement(SQL);
    ResultSet ResultSet =pst.executeQuery();
    try {   
        while(ResultSet.next()){
            String c =ResultSet.getString(1);
            System.out.println(c);
            this.txt_registro.setText(String.valueOf(c));
        } 
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoqNuevo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta : Fue una respuesta mas acotada y sin tantas vueltas

```
void numeros(){
    String sql ="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(nregistro)+1 as nregistro FROM muestras ORDER BY nregistro DESC LIMIT 1";
    conectar cc = new conectar();
//    Connection cn = (Connection) cc.conexion();
    try {
        java.sql.Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            //Aca le digo que muestre el valor en un JtextFiel

            lb_registro.setText(rs.getString("nregistro"));

        }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        // NOTA: So hubo error muestra el error
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Suponiendo que la consulta funciona y que estás llamando al método `numeros()` desde el constructor (o un post-constructor), deberías hacerle un `repaint()` para que se vean los cambios en pantalla.

Es todo lo que puedo ver sin tener la forma en que llamas al método y el error que te muestra (si es que te muestra algún error).

Comment: La consulta funciona, como seria la sintaxis del repaint() ? 

txt_registro.repaint(c); algo así? porque me arroja error